# Kotlin Firebase get specific data from field

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem because I want to get every languages[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5iEz.png) from all Decks. I cannot get there. I tried like this:

```
 document.data["languages"][1] <--- error
```

Only works this:

```
document.data["languages"]
```

But this above returns me all languages, but I want to get only second language from the array and do distinct from this list. How to get this? Now my code looks like this:

```
val documents = db.collection("Decks")
        .get()
        .await()

    val languages = documents?.mapNotNull { document ->
        document.data["languages"] as String
    }
```

Any tips?

Here is how looks my database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to deal with that type of field:

```
document.data["languages"][1]
```

[DocumentSnapshot#getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) method, returns an object of type `Map<String, Any>`. When you try to read the value that corresponds to a specific key, you actually don't know what kind of object is returned. It can be an array or any other object that is one of the [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Seeing your document, the "languages" field is indeed an array, so you need to cast the object to a List. In order to get the second element, please use the following line of code:

```
val en = (document.data["languages"] as List<String>)[1]
```

If you try to log this value, you'll get as result:

```
en
```